# lexicographic depth-first search complexity class

Tags: complexity-theory, search-algorithms

It seems to me to be incorrect to say that lexicographic DFS is P-complete, since it isn't a decision problem. There is a corresponding decision problem, first DFS ordering, which is known to be P-complete. However, I want to talk about complexity of DFS, not it's decision problem. What complexity class should I say DFS belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal name for a problem where you want to actually produce the solution as the output (not just say yes or no to whether one exists) is a [Function Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem) if every input has an associated output, or a [Search Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem) if some inputs might not have any solution (of course a function problem is just a special case of a search problem).

In this case, every graph has a lexicographic depth first ordering, so for any graph there is some output that can be produced, and you have a function problem. The class of function problems that can be computed in deterministic polynomial time is (cunningly) called [FP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_%28complexity%29).

Going out on a limb (with regards to my knowledge, someone else might be able to confirm this), I suspect that the obvious relationship<sup>1</sup> between P and FP holds for complete problems too, so your problem should also be FP-complete.

1. Note that this relationship normally relies on Turing reductions, but seeing as P=co-P there shouldn't be too much of a problem here.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense, the confusing fact was that in a research paper I was reading somebody was calling DFS a P-complete problem, which was somewhat of an abuse (so it seemed).